# LGBM Intuition to Non-technical individuals

Tags: machine-learning, python, boosting, ensemble-learning, communication

How can i explain LGBM to a non-technical person as it involves Trees/Ensembling and much more?
Using LGBM for solving a Regression problem and how does it helps in:

> 1. Better Prediction
> 2. Feature Importance distribution.
> 3. Which hyper-parameters to focus more.

Comment: There are lots of pages about gbm (that you need to explain in order to explain lgbm) on the net .. [http://uc-r.github.io/gbm_regression]  and for lgbm : [https://medium.com/@pushkarmandot/https-medium-com-pushkarmandot-what-is-lightgbm-how-to-implement-it-how-to-fine-tune-the-parameters-60347819b7fc]

Comment: Page not found for both the links

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault . just remove the last "]" in the url's ..

Comment: Don't make life difficult. Non-technical individuals have no reason to understand or have an intuition about LightGBM. What you might need to do is give them a basic idea of what boosting is. LightGBM vs "other ensemble algorithm name" is an implementation detail. The Wikipedia article on [boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)) has more than enough details for a non-technical individual. (Also, neither of the three points is strictly true, especially the third one "*Which hyper-parameter...*" is model-dependant and opaque for anyone not using LightGBM anyway.)

Comment: I get your point. The main motive for this intuition is basically, how to convey them **how the boosting is making better predictions than normal RF Model** as they fail to understand that **every tree learns on the errors incurred by the previous tree/learner**.

Answer (score 1):

In general, boosting algorithms use smaller batches and new small trees learn from the errors of the previous small trees, thus gradually decrease the error and increase the accuracy. At the end they are ensembled.
More intuitive info in Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightGBM